# What is the way to know that the endpoint is down if there is an L4 / L7 balancer?

Tags: rest, web, load-balancing, fuzzing

I'm writing a fuzzer and I want to detect if a sequence cause falling down of an endpoint of some service. Of course I can get 500 response code, but it's may be called from code of an endpoint. And there are any exact way to find out if a server is down?

I don’t know in advance what kind of balancing is on the service side. So I will be glad to know a universal solution, or some particular one.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to get creative, as the details will depend on the implementation under test. I would start with:

1. Read error responses to see if you can tell where they're coming from.
2. Check HTTP headers for hints.
3. Collect various kinds of errors and look for differences between them.